# Problem 19A, page 140, Stephen Willard, General Topology

Tags: general-topology

My question is whether or not there is an error in the definition of open sets on line 3 and 4 of Problem 19A on page 140 of Stephen Willard's "General Topology". It says "where $L$ is a compact subset of $Y$". On the wiki page for Alexandroff extension, it says (with different notation) "where $L$ is a closed and compact subset of $Y$". I was unable to solve part 2 of the problem "$Y^\ast$ is compact" without using the wiki definition of $L$.

I note that the definition in problem 19A is the same as Definition 19.2 on page 136 except that in the latter case, he is restricting his definition to Hausdorff spaces where compact implies closed. In the problem, he drops the restriction and can no longer rely on closure by this means.

I am reluctant to say for sure that this is an error since there may be a way of solving part two without the assumption that $L$ is closed.

Here is problem 19A:
The procedure used to obtain the one-point compactification $X^\ast$ of a locally compact non-compact Hausdorff space $X$ can be applied to any space Y. That is, $Y^\ast = Y \cup \{p\}$ with neighborhoods of $y \in Y$ unchanged in $Y^\ast$ while neighborhoods of $p$ have the form $\{p\} \cup (Y - L)$ where $L$ is a compact subset of $Y$. $Y^\ast$ is called the Alexandroff extension of $Y$.

Comment: State the full problem so that everyone knows what you are talking about.

Comment: I edited the question to include the full problem. How do I indicate the union of sets?

Comment: use \cup in LaTeX

Comment: Thanks. How do I indicate element inclusion \in?

Answer (score 3):

The correct definition is (for general spaces $Y$) a "closed and compact subset of $Y$".

For Hausdorff spaces $Y$ the closed part is redundant. $Y^\ast$ is compact in either definition but the "closed" part ensures that $Y$ as a subspace of $Y^\ast$ keeps the same topology, so that we have a real compactification (and $h(y)=y, h: Y \to Y^\ast$ is an embedding).

But for compactness of $Y^\ast$ we only need co-compact neighbourhoods of $\infty$ (the new point): consider open covers of $Y^\ast$, and the open set that contains $\infty$ has compact complement...

In summary: for the exercise we don't need the closed part; everything works without it. If we want $Y$ to embed into $Y^\ast$ we do need it even though it will only be a real (Hausdorff) compactification (in Willard's sense) iff $Y$ is Hausdorff and locally compact. In the sense he defines it in the exercise, it's an *extension* of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this Henno Brandsma. I don't understand your answer. You start by saying that the correct definition includes the word "closed", but then you say that the problem "Show that $Y^*$ is compact" can be solved whether the word "closed" is included or not.

Comment: @LifetimeBeginner If we want a compactification (as Willard also defines it) we need the closed, or the inclusion is not always an embedding. But for the statements of the exercise just compact is enough.

Comment: Thank you. Willard's definition of compactification is Definition 19.1 on page 135. He states: A compactification of a space X is an ordered pair (K, h) where K is a compact Hausdorff space and h is an embedding of X as a dense subset of K. Can we make $Y^*$ Hausdorff when Y isn't?

Comment: Where can I find the sketch of proof?

Comment: @LifetimeBeginner I added a skecth to the answer.  No, if $Y^\ast$ is Hausdorff as a compactification (!) then so must $Y$ be, hence the original restriction to Hausdorff spaces $Y$.

Comment: What can I make of problem 19A? When he relaxes the condition of Hausdorff on Y, he seems to prevent $Y^*$ from being a compactification.

Comment: He never says in problem 19A that the result $Y^*$ of the process is a compactification. Instead he calls it the Alexandroff extension. Therefor, it seems that he doesn't need "closed" in the definition after all.

Comment: @LifetimeBeginner He could partially salvage it by using the "closed and compact" clause in $Y^\ast$: then the inclusion is an embedding but $Y^\ast$ is only Hausdorff when $Y$ is locally compact Hausdorff. A non-Hausdorff space (non-Tychonoff really) does not have any **compactification** in the Willard sense. Hence the *extension* terminology.